# How to use stack bars from chartist in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chartist.js

I am referring chartist docs -> https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/examples.html#stacked-bar

I have seen the code in above link so I am trying to implement it in react component.

chart.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ChartistGraph from "react-chartist";

const simpleChartData = {
          labels: ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'],
          series: [
            [800000, 1200000, 1400000, 1300000],
            [200000, 400000, 500000, 300000],
            [100000, 200000, 400000, 600000]
          ],
        stackBars: true
}

class Chart extends Component {

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
            <ChartistGraph data={simpleChartData} type={'Bar'} /> 
      </div>

    )}

}

export default Chart;
```

I am not getting stacked bar charts instead I am getting simple bar charts. See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Try placing `stackBars: true` into options property of `ChartistGraph`

Comment: @SachiTekina No it doesn't work.

Comment: How did you implement it?

Comment: @SachiTekina Yeah there was a typo `options={ }` Works fine can you write an answer

Comment: I have written the answer below.

Comment: @SachiTekina Can you please help me here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50733529/how-to-use-plugins-with-chartist-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing `stackBars: true` into options property of `ChartistGraph`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ChartistGraph from "react-chartist";

const simpleChartData = {
          labels: ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'],
          series: [
            [800000, 1200000, 1400000, 1300000],
            [200000, 400000, 500000, 300000],
            [100000, 200000, 400000, 600000]
          ]

}

const options = {
     stackBars: true
}
class Chart extends Component {

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
            <ChartistGraph data={simpleChartData} options={options} type={'Bar'} /> 
      </div>

    )}

}

export default Chart;
```

Comment: Can you please help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51011612/how-to-style-elements-for-responsive-web-design