# How to use plugins with chartist.js?

Tags: reactjs, chartist.js

I am using chartist.js for making pie chart component. I want to make use of legend plugin https://codeyellowbv.github.io/chartist-plugin-legend/

I am not getting the legend in my pie chart. See screenshot below

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ChartistGraph from "react-chartist";
import Legend from "chartist-plugin-legend";

import './piechart.css';

let options = {
  width:400,
  height:500,
  labelInterpolationFnc: function(value) {
    return value[0]
  }
};


let plugin = {
    plugin:'legend'
}


class Chart extends Component {

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
          <div className="center">
          <ChartistGraph data={data} options={options} plugins={plugin} type="Pie"/>
          </div>
      </div>

    )}

}

export default Chart;
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: make sure label takes up an array

Comment: also, try `plugin:Legend`

Comment: @SachiTekina No not working.

Comment: @SachiTekina I tried this -> `let plugin = [
    plugin:Legend
]` does not work

Comment: How about `let plugin ={ plugin:Legend}`?

Comment: @SachiTekina Still not working. Am I importing it correctly ?

Comment: Check the docs : https://github.com/CodeYellowBV/chartist-plugin-legend#usage

Comment: @SachiTekina I have seen that but how can I use it with reactjs because I am using react-chartist which is a wrapper around chartist.js

Comment: What is the value of wickets ? Give a sandbox link for this example

Comment: @stack26 It has nothing to do with wickets it is just an array of objects

Comment: @stack26 I am not able to get how to add `plugins` for `react-chartist`

Comment: @stack26 Is this line correct -> `import Legend from "chartist-plugin-legend";`

Comment: Is someone able to add plugins to react-chartist today? Specifically tooltip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try folowing as the chartist-plugin-legend return Chartist.plugins.legend function. You can pass options also to add customization here is link where you can read it: [Link chartist-plugin-legend](https://github.com/CodeYellowBV/chartist-plugin-legend)

```
let plugins = [
    Legend()
]
```

Made this change also as react-chartist doesnot take any props called plugins.

```
<ChartistGraph data={data} options={{...options, plugins}} type="Pie"/>
```

Now add a .css file in your directory and import it in your component file. with following content. The content is same as mentioned on the plugin page.

```
.ct-legend {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;

    li {
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 23px;
        margin-bottom: 3px;
    }

    li:before {
        width: 12px;
        height: 12px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        content: '';
        border: 3px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 2px;
    }

    li.inactive:before {
        background: transparent;
    }

    &.ct-legend-inside {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
    }

    @for $i from 0 to length($ct-series-colors) {
        .ct-series-#{$i}:before {
            background-color: nth($ct-series-colors, $i + 1);
            border-color: nth($ct-series-colors, $i + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can give styling as you want. legend plugin also provides certains options that you can send. Read about it and accordingly pass in the options

Comment: I am getting unexpected token `...`

Comment: I think react-chartist does not work with chartist-plugin-legend

Comment: options should be an object options={{...options, plugins}} . That's the change. now it should work properly

Comment: I am getting output -> https://imgur.com/a/uzg5Fq5 but not like this -> https://codeyellowbv.github.io/chartist-plugin-legend/

Comment: good now you can add css, start with the base css mentioned on website. Wait let me edit my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172658/discussion-between-stack26-and-stone-rock).

Comment: Hi @simbathesailor, I'm trying to do the same with another plugin called 'tooltip' without success. I tried doing everything the same.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the plugin by adding it on the `options` property, but first you need to import the ff. dependencies:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ChartistGraph from "react-chartist";
import Legend from "chartist-plugin-legend";
```

add the plugin:

```
let options = {
    width:400,
    height:500,
    plugins: [
        Legend()
    ]
};
```

Render it: `<ChartistGraph data={data} options={options} type={type} />`

and because the CSS is not included, you can examine the index file of the [plugin here](https://github.com/CodeYellowBV/chartist-plugin-legend/blob/master/index.html) and play with it.

Comment: I am getting output -> https://imgur.com/a/uzg5Fq5 but not the one like this -> https://codeyellowbv.github.io/chartist-plugin-legend/

Comment: Yah, you need to include the CSS.

Comment: No proper documentation is available for it. How can we style the chart as we are using component `Chartist`.

Comment: You actually include it in your index.html

Comment: Ok but my web app has many components adding in index.html will be bad idea.

Comment: Then import it on the specific component, create a css file..if it in the same directory of your component, you can import it like this `import './legend.css';`

Comment: You did not got my point. If I want to customize CSS I have seen in docs they use `.ct-chart` or `.ct-labels` but such class does not exist in my component.

Comment: It will be "styled" even the class does not exist in the component as it will be generated by the plugin.